# Subject or object adjective clause (comma's necessity)

Tags: adjective-phrases

I can't clear up to which type of adjective clause the following refers.

> I can't say I'm the best challenger that has ever applied for this aid.

In object clauses we are able to omit "that" or other adjective pronouns.

I've just found the example:

> I'm a student that needs a car.

It has the same meaning.

So, I understand it correctly, don't I?

Furthermore, if this is so, I should had written:

> I can't say that I'm the best challenger that has ever applied for this aid.

Am I right?

Comment: You can't omit that here, the sentence would then make no sense. Also, /the best challenger who has ever applied/ is better.

Comment: @Lambie: Google Books claims many written instances of [*the first ever asked.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+first+ever+asked%22) Pedants might complain about missing ***that***, and some might think it's a bit "dialectal", but I don't think you can say it "makes no sense".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  That phrase cannot be put into the OP's sentence and have it retain the meaning he is looking for. The sentence needs who (formal grammar) or that (informal, "how people talk").

Comment: @Lambie: I don't know about your *who/that* formal/informal distinction, but in *my* vernacular it's fine to say, for example, *You're the first person ever objected to this construction.* You might say it's dialectal and/or "sloppy", but it's common enough. And easily understood even if you wouldn't use it yourself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That frankly strikes me as speaking without thinking. Like the sheriff getting on camera for the first time and making a sloppy delivery. It passes the "but people say it test" but it does not pass the "give advice to ELL learners" test. Finally, you might want to direct your remarks at SteveES's answer rather than at me. I was just pointing out the who thing, which is merely standard and therefore might interest Anthony.

Comment: @Lambie: SteveES's answer makes the point that relativizers *can be omitted, especially in speech or informally,* which is good enough for me. I think it's important learners be made aware that *in practice*, native speakers often ignore (some but not all) types of "rules" promoted by grammarians. In the long run, if the OP here wants to get as close as possible to passing for a native Anglophone, he'd do better taking on board that ***comma's necessity*** in the title is a stronger indicator of "non-native speaker" than would be omitting *both* relativizers in his example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I  never said one cannot omit the that. I said that in ***your sentence*** it would not work. In fact, in good writing one must remove it. No good editor leaves in unnecessary thats. Here is the rule: "The relative pronoun can only be omitted when it is the object of the clause. When the relative pronoun is the subject of the clause, it cannot be omitted." In "You are the first person who or that has ever objected to this construction", the word who or that is not the OBJECT of the clause: It cannot be left out. It is the subject.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm well aware of the grammarians' position on such matters. I'm simply making the point that *in practice* native speakers don't always observe this particular "prescriptive rule". So strictly speaking it's not so much *it cannot be omitted* as *it **should not** be omitted*, and failure to do so doesn't result in utterances that *make no sense* (however much it gets up prescriptive grammarians' noses! :) After all, people do actually say [You're the first person ever said that](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+first+person+ever+said+that%22) at least *sometimes.*

Comment: Some thats and whos simply should not be omitted.  ***You're the first person who ever said that to me***. You're the first person ever said that to me/ is sociologically marked speech. Whether you like it or  not. It just is. Just like: I ain't goin' is sociologically marked. It's a bad idea to confuse what you believe is prescriptivism with register. The only way to even identify things is in relation to other things. There is always some type of prescriptivism, otherwise, I could say in English: I have 30 years old instead of I am 30 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first two examples, the included "that"s are being used in a **[relative clause](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/relative.htm)**. In a relative clause, the relativizer (that, which, who e.t.c) can safely be omitted when the relative clause has a non-subject gap. But with a subject gap, it's **not** possible. Thus, in your example, the  "that" cannot be omitted because the relative clause has a subject gap(which I mark with <strike>strike</strike>).

> I'm a student that[<strike>a student</strike> needs a car.] *(The gap is in the subject position, so the relativizer cannot be omitted).*

The omission of the relativer is possible with a non-subject(object or compement of a preposition) gap.

> The money (that) [you are looking for <strike>the money</strike>] *(The gap or missing constituent is the complement of the preposition "for". So the relativizer is optional.)*
>
> The earrings (that) [my mom wore <strike>the earrings</strike>] *(Again, the relativizer is optional because the gap is in the position of the direct object)*

In the final example:

> I can't say **that** I'm the best challenger that has ever applied for this aid.

The first **that** (which you omit from the first example) can be included or omitted. This is an example of a **[reporting verb + that clause](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-that-clause)**, where the "that" *can* be omitted, especially in speech or informally. In more formal English, you should probably keep the first "that".

---

Some further reading on omitting "that"s may be found [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/omitting-%E2%80%9Cthat%E2%80%9D).

Comment: The most complete explanation I've ever seen. It is very clear now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov Not so complete. "that" can omitted when the relative clause has a non-subject gap. So that means, it can also be omitted when it's an obj of preposition. "The fact (that) you were talking about".

Comment: Thanks for editing. I haven't upvoted yet. The simpler way to explain it is that the gap is in the position of the preposition's compelement(which is after "for"). That-omision is possible with this kind of gap.

Comment: @user178049 Sorry, I misunderstood your comment and didn't really think enough about it! As far as I understand, your example **is** following the rule, as **that** is an object in it (so can be left out), not the subject? Or are you saying that "that" becomes the object in a relative clause when there is a non-subject gap?

Comment: @SteveES No, the relativizer doesn't become the obj. It just *stands for it*. So filling the gap will be redundant. *"The fact (that) you told the fact to me". Actually, there is no answer to "why that can be omitted". It's just a relativizer in a relative clause with a non-subject gap can be omitted

Comment: Why not say relative pronoun instead of relativizer which really  isn't even a word. What do you mean the gap IS the subject??

Comment: @Lambie Because the term is shorter and a relativizer isn't always a pronoun.